# Contact potential employer about erroneous assessment questions or not?

Tags: interviewing, test

This was a relatively simple assessment but two of the questions I consider to be erroneous or suspect at best. I reached out to the person that sent me the assessment and voiced my concerns after getting every question but those two correct. Was this the right thing to do or have I served to alienate myself in the eyes of the person hiring?

This was not in an interview. It was an online assessment that presumably other candidates are also taking. There isn't an ability to speak in person when you perhaps disagree on a question.

Should I have contacted potential employer about erroneous assessment questions?

Edit: I just received a response email where the employer indicated they have received similar feedback on these questions. I guess that solves this.

Comment: How did you "voice your concerns"?

Comment: Did you double-check the answers with any friends or coworkers to make sure that you are absolutely correct?

Comment: I sent an email and as professionally as I could asked for clarification on the question without accusing them off making a mistake or anything. I'm 100% sure about these answers especially after verifying with various online resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you do if your interviewer is wrong?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/what-do-you-do-if-your-interviewer-is-wrong)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4314/how-to-tell-a-interviewer-that-he-is-wrong-on-a-technical-question

Comment: @Justaguy1 - if you feel like your question is different than these possible duplicates, maybe you can edit to show those differences. Otherwise, you may find that these questions give you what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate because this wasn't an interview it was a pre interview online assessment. They're very different mediums with different weight.

Comment: Depends on the significance of the error. Was it a grammatical mistake or something that completely changes your answer.

Comment: For one of them there are two possible answers but one is considered incorrect and the other question the correct answer is flat out incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell a interviewer that he is wrong on a technical question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4314/how-to-tell-a-interviewer-that-he-is-wrong-on-a-technical-question)

Answer (score 3):

> Should I have contacted potential employer about erroneous assessment questions?

IMO, Yes. Once you've confirmed that the question / input / output behavior is incorrect, let the employer know politely.

On one hand, this helps the employer correct the question not just for you, but also for other candidates in future, and any past ones on the border of cutoff. So good Karma.

On other hand, some of the employers may be using such questions *knowingly* as a means for checking how many candidates figure out that actually the question itself is wrong. This too can prove to be a valuable practical skill in real life.

Comment: +1 for the second case.  I had an onsite interview once where the coding question (on paper) had an error in it.  I crossed out the incorrect code, corrected it and then provided the answer.  The interviewer brought it up in a very positive light and I did get the job.  I never did know whether it was by design or just a mistake but it clearly worked in my favor

Comment: Emphasis on the "polite" context of the feedback. If you do provide feedback, it will be important to separate it from any feelings or feedback about why you did not get the job. Try to present it as independently as possible. If your feedback is done in the context of "I didn't get the job and it's because your evaluation is wrong" your feedback may be dismissed because you came across as bitter vs helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine to do that as long as you're not being too confrontational about it.

Simply ask that the recruiting team take a second look at the tests to see if they're representative of the role being offered.

You're not likely to run into these people again, so you don't really have anything to lose here, and there's always a possibility you might get called back (but don't count on it).